# Overloading public methods

Tags: java, overloading

Are these 2 methods overloaded?

```
private static int howManyChar (String s, char c, int index)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (index >= s.length())
        return 0;
    if (s.charAt (index) == c)
        count++;
    count+=howManyChar (s, c, ++index);
    return count;
}

public static int howManyChar (String s, char c)
{
    if (s.length()==0)
        return 0;
    else
        return howManyChar (s, c, 0);
}
```

I am just not sure if it matters if one of the methods is public and the other private...
I think they are overloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they're overloaded. Within a class, accessibility is irrelevant to overloading. However, accessibility matters in that it's fine to have one private method in a base class with the same signature as another method in a derived class.

Obviously from outside your class, only `howManyChar(String, char)` is going to be visible.

Comment: another question. is the second method a recursive method?

Comment: @user3623592: No, it's not calling itself. The first method is recursive though.